# add padding to HTML anchor that has a background-image

Tags: html, css, anchor, background-image

I have a basic anchor as below and I would like have the background 10x10px, however importantly i'd like to have 1em of padding around the image and not margin so that, on mobile devices it is clickable.

The problem is, as i'm using a background the margin makes the image become tiled across the full area and doesn't increase the clickable area.

Is there a way to use padding and maintain a 10x10px background on the anchor?

```
<a id="page_close" href="/course/"></a>

#page_close {
    background-image: url("/images/close.png");
    height: 10px;
    margin: 1em;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    text-indent: -9999px;
    top: 0;
    width: 10px;
}
```

This is `close.png` sprite image:

[image: My close sprite]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go.

```
#page_close {
    background-image: url("https://i.stack.imgur.com/sw4qj.png");
    background-position: 0% 0%;
    padding: 3em;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0; right: 0;
    text-indent: -9999px;
    width: 10px; height: 10px;
    background-clip: content-box;
    background-origin: content-box;
}
```

The trick is to use both `background-origin` and `background-clip` to position the background in the middle of the clickable area.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/MrLister/Xe5sE/1/

Comment: Excellent answer and many thanks for introducing me to `background-origin` and `background-clip`.

Answer (score 1):

```
#page_close {
    background-image: url("/images/close.png");
    padding: 10px;
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    height: 10px;
    margin: 1em;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    text-indent: -9999px;
    top: 0;
    width: 10px;
}
```

`background-size` might help

Hope this helps :)

***if not just do this:***

**HTML**

```
<a id="page_close" href="/course/"><img src="images/close.png" class="close"/></a>
```

**CSS**

```
 #page_close {
        height: 10px;
        width: 10px;
        margin: 1em;
        position: absolute;
        right: 0;
        padding: 10px;
        text-indent: -9999px;
        top: 0;
        width: 10px;
    }
    .close {
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
    }
```